# Android : TextView showing Package name instead of the actual text

Tags: java, android

Text View in my fragment_main should be showing the String but instead it is showing the package name.

[image: TextView should show sth]

In my Main Activity Class,

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {   


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView main_list;
    ArrayAdapter<Cinema> adapter;
    ArrayList<Cinema> ItemList = new ArrayList<Cinema>();

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v("Check", "1");
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        ItemList.addAll(initialization());
        ListView main_list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainlist);
        adapter = new ListAdapater(rootView.getContext(), ItemList);
        main_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        main_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(rootView.getContext(), CinemaDetails.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putParcelable("Cinema", ItemList.get(position));
                i.putExtra("Bundle", b);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public ArrayList<Cinema> initialization () {
        ArrayList<Cinema> tempItemList = new ArrayList<Cinema>();
        ArrayList<Movie> movielistone = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        Movie movieone = new Movie(101, "MovieOne", "null", 5, "nULL");
        Movie movietwo = new Movie(102, "Movietwo", "null", 3, "nuLL");
        movielistone.add(movieone);
        movielistone.add(movietwo);
        Cinema cinemaone = new Cinema(01, "test", "ygn", 55555, movielistone, 3);
        Cinema cinematwo = new Cinema(02, "test2", "ygn", 554555, movielistone, 3);
        tempItemList.add(cinemaone);
        tempItemList.add(cinematwo);
        return tempItemList;
    }
}
```

I use Array Adapter and the code for it is

```
public class ListAdapater extends ArrayAdapter<Cinema> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public ListAdapater(Context context, List<Cinema> itemList) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, R.id.txt_cinemaname, itemList );
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context) ;  
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Cinema getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getItem(position);
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cinema cinema = this.getItem(position);
    TextView txt_name;
    TextView txt_movie;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        txt_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cinemaname);
        txt_movie = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_moviesonshow);
        convertView.setTag(new ItemViewHolder(txt_name, txt_movie));
    } else {
        ItemViewHolder viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        txt_name = viewHolder.getName();
        txt_movie = viewHolder.getMoviename();
    }

    txt_name.setText("test");
    Log.v("name", txt_name.getText().toString());
    txt_movie.setText("");
    for (Movie movie : cinema.getMovieonshow()) {
        String temp = txt_movie.getText().toString();
        txt_movie.setText(temp + movie.getName() + "\n");
    }
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public static class ItemViewHolder {
    private TextView name;
    private TextView moviename;
    public ItemViewHolder() {}
    public ItemViewHolder(TextView name, TextView moviename) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.moviename = moviename;
    }
    public TextView getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(TextView name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public TextView getMoviename() {
        return moviename;
    }
    public void setMoviename(TextView moviename) {
        this.moviename = moviename;
    }
}}
```

I have never had this problem before. I tied to log the Text from the TextView and it shows "test" just like I put it there. Any suggestion? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you also post movie.getName() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite figure out exactly, but why are you passing in `R.id.txt_cinemaname` in your ListAdapter constructor? The problem looks like you are passing in an Object (that string "com.example... is a pointer to an object, I'm guessing a TextView) rather than a string.

Also, shouldn't you be returning `convertView` rather than `super.getView(position, convertView, parent);` in your `getView()` method?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is

```
return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

`ArrayAdapter`, by default, fills the `TextView` view at the specified resource id (in this case `R.id.txt_cinemaname`) with the result of `item.ToString()` (where `item` is the object at the specified position in the backing array).

Since `Cinema` does not implement `toString()`, the default text is produced.

Using `return convertView;` should fix it.